# Move Lat & Lon point to a new routable position

Tags: python, gps, openstreetmap, map-matching

I'm collecting raw data from a GPS. It looks not very accurate:

[image: gps raw data]

I would like to move points to nearest routable point ( in a offline cleaning process if it is possible )

What I did:

I digging on forums searching for a magic solution ;) May be, the closest is to use openstreetmap extract and query it, something like:

```
(
  way
  (around:100,41.12345,4.12345)
  [highway~"^(primary|secondary|tertiary|residential)$"]
  [name];
>;)
```

But I have no experience in this environment, I don't know how to make query and get desired new point ( python will be wonderful, but I'm open to other solutions ).

Perhaps I'm totally wrong. I have my mind open to any solution.

Comment: 'map matching' is the correct tag that you have already used for your 'magic solution'. Append OSM or open source and you find some ;)

Comment: Hi @Karussell, srr, confused aboud your comment. Thanks? I answered a lot of questions in SO, I hope, now, someone helps me.

Comment: I can't provide a solution, but what you have found is an Overpass query. This one will search for all ways (roads/lines) in a 100m radius around that coordinate, you can test it here http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/euC

Comment: @danihp sorry for being cryptic, see now the answer from scai

Comment: @Karussell, I didn't know if cryptic or sarcastic, I'm worried about it. I know my question was vague. At this moment my approach is to work with raw xml OSM data. OSM is awesome. Have a nice day.

Comment: @danihp sorry, again. I was just confused that you had the correct magic word 'map matching' which returns useful links at the main internet search providers ...

Comment: @Karussell, I saw the links, but wasn't useful for me. Thanks about your comments bro.

Answer (score 2):

There are various solutions for [Map Matching (also called Conflation) with OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Conflation) available, for example GraphHopper.

Also take a look at this [related question on gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/different-approaches-for-map-matching-links-ideas).